# Count itab rows that meet some condition?

Tags: abap, internal-tables

I get a internal table from a Function Module call that returns ~ 100 rows. About 40% of the rows are not relevant to me because I only need the entries with `PAR1 = "XYZ"`.
On SQL tables (transparent tables), I can use a

```
select count(*) from tab where PAR1 = "XYZ"
```

to get the number of valid entries.

Looking at the documentation, all I could find was the READ Table syntax to iterate through the table. My current approach is to basically have a loop and increase if the row contains the value I want. But this seems very inefficient.

Is there a better approach for my requirement?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Do whatever feels right to you. With ~100 rows, virtually nothing will make a huge difference in runtime. For me, stability would be more important than speed in this case.

That being said, you could try this:

```
LOOP AT lt_my_table TRANSPORTING NO FIELDS WHERE par1 = 'XYZ'.
  ADD 1 TO l_my_counter.
ENDLOOP.
```

Answer (score 13):

As from 740 SP05 you can use:

```
DATA(lv_lines) = REDUCE i( INIT x = 0 FOR wa IN gt_itab
                    WHERE( F1 = 'XYZ' ) NEXT x = x + 1 ).
```

for counting the number of lines in gt_itab meeting codntion f1 = 'xyz'.

Comment: The only correct answer for modern programming. This can of course also be used in-line (`IF REDUCE...`) so you don't need to declare any variables. Though be careful: technically this declares both `x` and `wa`, though only once meaning that you can have multiple `REDUCE` expressions using the same result and work area variable names.

Comment: Thank you for that great answer!
Is it possible to put in multipe WHERE conditions to reduce results furthermore?

Comment: This worked for me - but only after adding a space between `WHERE` and `(`

Comment: @Lilienthal could you give an example how the code would look like without declaring any variables? I don't understand how it can work.

Comment: @Cold_Class Only if you're evaluating the result directly. Say if you want to run code X only if there are more than 5 lines you can do: `IF REDUCE #( .... ) > 5. [X]. ENDIF.` Any other approach to this problem requires declaring variables the regular way meaning they can't be used in-line.

Comment: @Lilienthal I think I gotcha - by "don't need to declare any variables" you just meant `lv_lines` in this case - right? Because I thought you found a way to also get rid of `x` and `wa`

Comment: @Cold_Class Ah yes, I just meant the `lv_lines` indeed. Sadly I don't think there's a way around needing to have those "temporary variables" declared.

Answer (score 6):

If the entries in the internal table are irrelevant you could do something like this.

```
DELETE lt_table WHERE par1 <> 'XYZ'.
```

Then you can count the remaining relevant records by using `lines( lt_table )` or `DESCRIBE TABLE lt_table LINES l_number_of_lines.`

Here is an example.

```
TYPES: BEGIN OF tt_test,
  par1 TYPE c LENGTH 3,
  END OF tt_test.

DATA: lt_table TYPE TABLE OF tt_test.
DATA: l_number_of_lines TYPE i.
FIELD-SYMBOLS: <fs_par1> LIKE LINE OF lt_table.

APPEND INITIAL LINE TO lt_table ASSIGNING <fs_par1>.
<fs_par1>-par1 = 'XYZ'.
APPEND INITIAL LINE TO lt_table ASSIGNING <fs_par1>.
<fs_par1>-par1 = 'ABC'.
APPEND INITIAL LINE TO lt_table ASSIGNING <fs_par1>.
<fs_par1>-par1 = 'XYY'.
APPEND INITIAL LINE TO lt_table ASSIGNING <fs_par1>.
<fs_par1>-par1 = 'XYZ'.
APPEND INITIAL LINE TO lt_table ASSIGNING <fs_par1>.
<fs_par1>-par1 = 'XYZ'.

l_number_of_lines = LINES( lt_table ).
WRITE / l_number_of_lines.
DESCRIBE TABLE lt_table LINES l_number_of_lines.
WRITE / l_number_of_lines.
DELETE lt_table WHERE par1 <> 'XYZ'.
l_number_of_lines = LINES( lt_table ).
WRITE / l_number_of_lines.
```

Answer (score 1):

Variant with FOR should also work, however it requires declared table type of that table:

```
TYPES: tt_mara TYPE TABLE OF mara WITH EMPTY KEY.
DATA(count) = lines( VALUE tt_mara( FOR line IN lt_mara WHERE ( matnr = 'XXX' ) ( line ) ) ).
```